# Android - define "context" in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm a newbie in Android application programming (even in Java).
I have my own data from my weather stations and I decode them in background from JSON - that all wokrs fine.

in the "onPostExecute" function I call another function called "save". And in this function i need "context".

**How do I define this "context"? or where should I take it from? Can you please direct me in my example?**

I tried some google variants, but each time the application stops working. (Android 5.1 - Lenovo P70) - I can not use a virtual device on my computer, so Iam testing my app directly on my phone after connecting with Android studio.

I will be grateful for any advice.

**Here is "fetchData.java" which contains a function "fetchData" which is called from "MainActivity.java" when i touch a button.**

```
package arduino.weatherstation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;



public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String data = "";
    private String dataParsed = "";
    private String singleParsed = "";
    private String last_data = "";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "lastdata.txt";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String result = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://***.cz");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }


            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleParsed =  "Day:" + JO.get("Day") + "\n"+
                                "Time:" + JO.get("Time") + "\n"+
                                "Temperature:" + JO.get("Temperature") + "\n"+
                                "Humidity:" + JO.get("Humidity") + "\n"+
                                "Pressure:" + JO.get("Pressure") + "\n"+
                                "Light:" + JO.get("Light") + "\n"+
                                "Rain:" + JO.get("Rain") + "\n"+
                                "City:" + JO.get("City") + "\n"+
                                "Country:" + JO.get("Country") + "\n"+
                                "Id:" + JO.get("Id") + "\n";
                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed;
                if(i == (JA.length() - 1)) {
                    last_data = "Day:" + JO.get("Day") + "\n"+
                            "Time:" + JO.get("Time") + "\n"+
                            "Temperature:" + JO.get("Temperature") + "\n"+
                            "Humidity:" + JO.get("Humidity") + "\n"+
                            "Pressure:" + JO.get("Pressure") + "\n"+
                            "Light:" + JO.get("Light") + "\n"+
                            "Rain:" + JO.get("Rain") + "\n"+
                            "City:" + JO.get("City") + "\n"+
                            "Country:" + JO.get("Country") + "\n"+
                            "Id:" + JO.get("Id") + "\n";
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.data.setText(last_data);       

        save(last_data);
    }

    public void save(String toSave) {
        String text = toSave;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(text.getBytes());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare a Context variable in your fetchData class like this

```
Context context;
```

Now make a constructor for fetchData and take context as an argument like this

```
public fetchData(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then wherever you are creating an object of fetchData pass the context form that class like

```
fetchData fetchObject = new fetchData(this);
fetchObject.execute();
```

When you are using context for file it will be available in your fetchData class context variable. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i want to create new fetchData(this) in  MainActivity.java: `click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetchData fetchObject = new fetchData(this);
                fetchObject.execute();

            }
        });` i have an error here now (mean text 'this'), maybe problem is with "OnClickListener()", can you please help me solve this too?

Comment: change this to MainActivity.this.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the context into FetchData from your Activity or wherever you're creating the FetchData object. If you can't figure out how to pass it through in the constructor, you could just add a setter method that you call before running the AsyncTask

Comment: Where can i put it in? in "onPostExecute" or in "fetchData"? or somewhere else?

Comment: I misread your question, I thought you were in an Activity. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for you answer, can you please give me some example how to get a "context" before I run the "AsyncTask"?

Comment: Well you're probably creating and running the task from your Activity, so you could just pass in "this" or the result of calling "getApplicationContext"

Comment: I was trying to figure something out, but it did not work well. Can you help me continue please?

i am creating it here:

`click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetchData process = new fetchData();
                process.execute();

            }
        });`

How can i add "context" to this? A lot of things are still difficult for me in JAVA. :/

Comment: FetchData is an object. Objects have constructors. Define a constructor for FetchData such that it takes and stores a reference to a Context object. Then you'll be able to access it from any non static scope inside of your FetchData class.

Answer (score 0):

In your class MainActivity.class add a method to set text to your TextView:

```
public void setTextMsg(String msg){
    TextView txtv=(TextView) R.id.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    txtv.setText(msg);
}
```

you can try add this in your class AsyncTask (fetchData):

```
private MainActivity mainactivity;

public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainactivity){
  this.mainactivity=mainactivity;
}
```

And in     postExecute(){}.    add this lines:

```
mainactivity.setTextMsg(last_data)
```

NOTE: When you can call to your AsyncTask do this:

```
fetchData dataThread=new fetchData();
dataThread.setMainActivity(MainActivity.this);
dataThread.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't know if you understand my question. I have a problem getting the "context" when iam saving the data to a text file.

Comment: if you use my way for get the context just do:
    Context context=mainactivity.getApplicationContext();

Comment: or you can pass a context by class async task into you class like this 
Context context;      public fetchData(Context context) { this.context = context;}